# What is the option in SQL to handle nested user defined table type from Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, stored-procedures, nested

We are migrating from Oracle to Azure SQL. In Oracle there are user defined table types which are nested. For example, Manager Table Type has `Employee Table` Type as one of the columns.
As far as I know `SQL server` doesn't allow nested table types. Maybe because it breaks the normal form, but `Oracle` allows it.
Now the challenge is one of the table type objects needs to be passed on to a stored procedure as a parameter from Java. How can we handle this in `SQL server` without flattening the structure in `Java`.
I thought of passing all table objects including parent and child, then declaring various sql tables types to receive them in SQL SP. But the challenge will be that the parent will have a reference to the child in the incoming parameter, how do I handle that in SQL?

Comment: You can make a foreign key between parent and child. When it comes to databases, always favour normalized structures rather than denormalized

Comment: Thanks Charlie face. Yeah I agree and I have the same opinion but here we are migrating an app from Java Oracle to Java SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the challenge is one of the table type object needs to be passed on to a stored procedure as a parameter from Java. How can we handle this in SQL server without flattening the structure in Java.

Use [JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).  JSON documents (and XML too for that matter) allow arbitrary data shapes to be passed from the client to the SQL Server and consumed there with [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  And there's no requirement to create user-defined table types for every different data shape you want to pass to the server.

If the Java developers would prefer to use XML, that will work too.

Comment: Thanks David for your reply. Really appreciate it. Yes I read about XML and JSON options but will it involve lots of change in Java( not sure at present). I was expecting some other way to handle in SQL. But definitely i will try this.

Comment: Hopefully there’s a Java class that maps to the table type, and you can just serialize that to JSON.